# Is there any way to export parts via command line in Musescore?

Tags: musescore

I export parts a lot in Musescore. I would like to do something like this:

```
$ musescore -i myScore.mscz --export-parts
Exporting myScore-piano.pdf
Exporting myScore-guitar.pdf
Exporting myScore-drums.pdf

Parts were successfully exported
$
```

Is this possible?

I did find this:

```
$ musescore --export-to myScore.pdf --export-score-parts myScore.mscz
```

However, this generates one single pdf with the partiture and the parts. I need them in separate files.

The closest solution I have found so far is a way to generate a file containing all the parts without the partiture. It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
IN=$1

PARTITURE=${IN%.mscz}-partiture.pdf
musescore -o $PARTITURE $IN

NO_PAGES_PARTITURE=$(pdftk $PARTITURE dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | cut -f2 -d ' ')
let NO_PAGES_PARTITURE=NO_PAGES_PARTITURE+1

FULL=${IN%.mscz}-full.pdf
musescore -o $FULL -P $IN

PARTS=${IN%.mscz}-all-parts.pdf
pdftk $FULL cat $NO_PAGES_PARTITURE-end output $PARTS

rm $FULL
```

Answer (score 6):

Using MuseScore 3 the easiest way to generate parts PDFs is with the json batch conversion.

In the same folder where `myScore.mscz` is located, create a new file `myScore_convert.json` with the following content:

```
[
  {
    "in": "myScore.mscz",
    "out": [
      "myScore.pdf",
      [ "myScore-", ".pdf"]
    ]
  }
]
```

Open a command window, change with `cd` to the location of your files and issue:

```
musescore3 --job myScore_convert.json
```

This will give the following result:

```
convert <myScore.mscz>...
restHeight < 0.0: -10277.032723

        to <myScore.pdf>
        part <myScore-Soprano.pdf>
        part <myScore-Alto.pdf>
        part <myScore-Tenor.pdf>
        part <myScore-Bass.pdf>
... success!
```

And with that 5 files.

You can find more examples with other file-types at the [MuseScore 3 handbook](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/3/command-line-options#Run_a_batch_job_converting_multiple_documents)

I've tested this on Ubuntu 18.04 with MuseScore3 3.2.3.

Answer (score 2):

> EDIT: It definitely has some bugs, but it does kindof work. Feel free to use it to create something on your own.

I have now created a Python script do do this. So far I have only tried it on one file, but it seems to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def main():
    import sys
    import os
    import json
    import subprocess
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
    
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Usage: getPartNames.py <filename>")
        exit

    inFile = sys.argv[1]
    filename, fileExtention = os.path.splitext(inFile)
    mscx = filename + ".mscx"
    
    if fileExtention not in [".mscx", ".mscz"]:
        print("Unknown file extention: " + fileExtention)
        exit
    
    if fileExtention == ".mscz":
        proc = subprocess.Popen(["musescore", "-o", mscx, "-P", inFile])
        proc.wait()
        
    tree = et.parse(mscx)

    scoreList = []
    
    for score in tree.iter('Score'):
        scoreList.append(score)

    data = []
    partList = []
    
    for i in range(len(scoreList)-1):
        name=""
        for trackName in scoreList[i+1].iter('trackName'):
            name = trackName.text
            partList.append(trackName)
            break

        tree.getroot().remove(scoreList[i])
        tree.getroot().append(scoreList[i+1])
        
        partFileBase = filename + "-" + name
        partFile = partFileBase + ".mscx"
        entry = {}
        entry['in'] = partFile
        entry['out'] = partFileBase + ".pdf"
        data.append(entry)
        tree.write(partFile)

    jsonfile = filename + '.json'
    with open(jsonfile, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile)

    proc = subprocess.Popen(["musescore", "-j", jsonfile])
    proc.wait()

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```